# Crontab script is not starting

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a simple script that cleans the logs with the following code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LOG_ROOT=...
cd $LOG_ROOT
find ./* -mtime +$DAYS -delete
```

And this is what in crontab:

`@midnight /opt/sas/system/cleanlogs.sh`

And it works just fine. But there's another script, that cleans sandboxes, that have the same code as *cleanlogs.sh*, except that it is run in another directory. It works from the command line, but does not start from crontab for some reason.

I'm confused because the scripts are almost identical and one is not working. What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you take a look at syslog under /var/log/syslog and have a look around midnight to see if you can spot any errors from crontab.

Comment: @OskarL I don't have permission to view it.

Comment: have you got sudo rights ? if so you can view it as sudo.

Comment: @OskarL no i don't have sudo rights, i agree it would be useful to see logs but i can't

Comment: @bac0n variable Days is defined i just forgot to write it in the code. Your version of the script works too but only from command line. Cron still doesn't start it.

Comment: Can you edit the script to add logging (e.g. redirecting output & errors to a file in /tmp or something like that)?

Comment: _“the scripts are almost identical”_ So what’s the difference? _You_ must find it yourself as we cannot access your machine. Compare the scripts with `diff`, check their permissions, the exact crontab calls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that scripts were not identical as i thought. Firstly, i added logging of cron with this

`@midnight /opt/sas/system/cleansandbox.sh > .../cron.log 2>&1`.

There was *#!/bin/bash - no such file or directory* error. So the script contained extra carriage return at the end of the first line, which i detected using this `$ head -1 cleansandbox.sh | od -c` and then corrected the script with this `sed -i '1s/^.*#//;s/\r$//' cleansandbox.sh`. Now it works from cron. Thanks everyone for the help!